# I'm trying to import historic notes from another excel sheet into my current sheet using a macro button but I am getting a debug error

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I click a button to run each of the macros. the debug seems to highlight 'headrow' on the extract results line.

'hyperoptic' is the workbook that the historic notes data is being imported into.

the sheet that the data needs to be imported into is 'notes history' which is a sheet within the hyperoptic workbook.

The headings in the 'notes history' are ([TM_CELL_ID]),([strCellID]),([strProgram]),([notes]),([Customer_Notes]),([strDate]). these headings are identical to the headings in the sheet where the data is being exported from.

The data is being imported from sheet EE_NG_Data_All_Orders_and_Notes

```vb
Sub Workbook_open()
    
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     
    Hyperoptic_Latest_data
    Portal_Data
    NIARequested
    UpdateNIAComp
    UpdateNotes
    UpdateNotesHistory
    Estimates
    Duplicate_Estimates_Delete
    New_Sites
    
    Sheets("Hyperoptic").Select
        
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        
    MsgBox "Report Updated", vbInformation
        
End Sub
        
Sub UpdateNotesHistory()
    Dim path As String
    Dim fName As String
    Dim ext As String
    Dim outSheet As String
    Dim outCell As String
    Dim strSql As String
    Dim strWHERE As String
    Dim tabName As String
    Dim headRow As Long
    Sheets("Note History").Select
    
    path = "\\etherserv2\EE_NG_Portal_Database\"
    
    fName = "EE_NG_Data_All_Orders_and_Notes"
    ext = "xlsb"
    outSheet = "Note History"
    outCell = "A1"
    
    strSql = " ([TM_CELL_ID]),([strCellID]),([strProgram]),([notes]),([Customer_Notes]),([strDate])"
    
    strWHERE = "Where [strProgram] = 'Hyperoptic' and [strDate] > #01/04/2022# and [Customer_Notes] = 'Yes' "
    
    tabName = "qryNigel_All_Orders_and_Notes"
    headRow = 1
    
    extract_results_xls path, fName, ext, outSheet, outCell, strSql, strWHERE, tabName, headRow
    TextNumberToNumber outSheet, "a2:a", "b"
     
End Sub
```

Comment: Where do you get an error? What error message do you get? How are the parameters of the _extract_results_xls_ sub/function defined?

Comment: I received error ' Compile error: Byref argument type mismatch' and headRow is highlighted yellow.  this is how extract_results sub function is defined:                    
       Sub extract_results_xls(ImpPath As String, _
         ImpFile As String, _
         ext As String, _
        OutputSht As String, _
   OutputCell As String, _
     Optional sqlStr As String, _
                            Optional sqlWhere As String, _
                            Optional tabName As String, _
                            Optional headerRow As String = "A1", Optional headstart As Integer)

Comment: _headerRow_ must by a string (e.g. "A1") according to the sub definition.